# Can we modify a layout (programmatically) before inflating it in a fragment?

Tags: android

I have a simple fragment:

```
public class FR_FragmentPopup extends Fragment {

    public FR_FragmentPopup() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MainActivity.getMain().doFragment(new FR_RecycleViewSettings2(),R.id.over_frame_bottom,false);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popup, container, false);
    }

}
```

I want to modify the xml to wrap height, but programmatically because I'm using the layout in other fragments also.I know that `R.layout.fragment_popup` is an `int` and not a `view` which makes it difficult to use edit it.

```
return inflater.inflate(
    findViewById(R.layout.fragment_popup).setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
    , container, false);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: BTW, the ` // Required empty public constructor` is not true, you do not have to make it public. Just do not provide any and it will be fine.

Comment: My mistake, I just wrote that comment for myself because that's what studio's error showed :)

Comment: Then Enok it is sad that mine answer which was original one in this thread is not accepted.

Comment: @jakubbialkowski I noticed you were the first one, and I wanted to click your's first, and I noticed the 2nd one was a bit more "fancy"(I got verry confused when android asked me which LayoutParams to import, there are 30 GDI!, he's answer marked which one to import)   and also that he forgot to edit one of the LayoutParams to MATCH_PARENT (both are set to WRAP_CONTENT). But in the end I thought both are just as good, I'll just upvote the underdog. But now I feel guilty. :|

Comment: It's okay @ThenEnok, he answered first, so he deserves it, fair enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popup, container, false);

view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

return view;
```

Practically:

Never tried.

Answer (score 2):

You may do as following:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help, container, false);
        rootView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return rootView;
    }
```